# How to loop through multiple lists sequentially with one loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

In **Python 3.6.3** Is there a way to loop though one list after another?

For example:

```
deck = [(value, suit) for value in range(2, 11) +
            ["J", "Q", "K", "A"] for suit in ["H", "C", "D", "S"]]
```

(In this case, I want to loop through the face cards right after the non-face cards.)

For clarification:
The above line throws a:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'
```

This is my problem.

Comment: Your example is unclear. What's the expected result/output?

Comment: @timgeb In the example, I'm trying to make a standard deck of 52 cards. The problem is that I want to iteration through {"J", "Q", "K", "A"} right after the numbered cards without needing a second loop.

Comment: @schwobaseggl This line throws a type error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'"

Comment: @Josh `range()` does not create a list in Python 3. It used to create a list in Python 2. [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) in Python 3 does create **an immutable sequence type**, not a list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) doesn't return a `list` in Python3, so `range(2, 10) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]` doesn't work, but `list(range(2, 10)) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]` does. You can also use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to concatenate iterables:

```
from itertools import chain 

chain(range(2, 10), ["J", "Q", "K", "A"])
# or even shorter:
chain(range(2, 10), "JQKA")  # as strings themselves are iterables

# so this comprehension will work
deck = [
   (value, suit) 
   for value in chain(range(2, 10), "JQKA") 
   for suit in "HCDS"
]
```

The nested comprehension does, of course, constitute a cartesian product which you can also use a util for:

```
from itertools import product
deck = list(product(chain(range(2, 10), "JQKA"), "HCDS"))
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem with your current code is here:

```
range(2, 10) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
```

First off, it should be `range(2, 11)`, otherwise, cards with the number 10 are omitted. Second, in order to join the range and the list, you'll have to do like so:

```
list(range(2, 11)) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
```

So the final result will be:

```
deck = [(value, suit) for value in list(range(2, 11)) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"] for suit in ["H", "C", "D", "S"]]
```

I think this will give you the desired output (first all non-face cards, then all face cards).

Comment: This will work, but @schwobaseggl has a better solution using itertools, since it does not require unnecessary construction of a list, and then list concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

See @schwobaseggl's solution for what you want, but I usually prefer to represent cards as a 2 character string, however:

```
deck = [r+s for r in '23456789TJQKA' for s in 'hcds']
```

This is more readable in my opinion, and will still behave a lot like a tuple of rank, suit.

Comment: No need for the `*`

Answer (score 3):

In Python3, you can use unpacking:

```
deck = [(value, suit) for value in [*range(2, 10), "J", "Q", "K", "A"] for suit in ["H", "C", "D", "S"]]
```

Comment: No need for the `list` call there: `[*range(2, 10), "J", "Q", "K", "A"]` is enough. (Or even `[*range(2, 11), *"JQKA"]`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson good to know. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

Focusing only in the error you do get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list

I will give you an explanation.

Your current code does work in **Python 2**:

```
deck = [(value, suit) for value in range(2, 11) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"] for suit in ["H", "C", "D", "S"]]
print deck
```

will print:

```
[(2, 'H'), (2, 'C'), (2, 'D'), (2, 'S'), (3, 'H'), (3, 'C'), (3, 'D'), (3, 'S'), (4, 'H'), (4, 'C'), (4, 'D'), (4, 'S'), (5, 'H'), (5, 'C'), (5, 'D'), (5, 'S'), (6, 'H'), (6, 'C'), (6, 'D'), (6, 'S'), (7, 'H'), (7, 'C'), (7, 'D'), (7, 'S'), (8, 'H'), (8, 'C'), (8, 'D'), (8, 'S'), (9, 'H'), (9, 'C'), (9, 'D'), (9, 'S'), (10, 'H'), (10, 'C'), (10, 'D'), (10, 'S'), ('J', 'H'), ('J', 'C'), ('J', 'D'), ('J', 'S'), ('Q', 'H'), ('Q', 'C'), ('Q', 'D'), ('Q', 'S'), ('K', 'H'), ('K', 'C'), ('K', 'D'), ('K', 'S'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'S')]
```

In **Python 3** you have to use `list(range(2, 11))`:

```
deck = [(value, suit) for value in list(range(2, 11)) + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"] for suit in ["H", "C", "D", "S"]]
print(deck)
```

will print:

```
[(2, 'H'), (2, 'C'), (2, 'D'), (2, 'S'), (3, 'H'), (3, 'C'), (3, 'D'), (3, 'S'), (4, 'H'), (4, 'C'), (4, 'D'), (4, 'S'), (5, 'H'), (5, 'C'), (5, 'D'), (5, 'S'), (6, 'H'), (6, 'C'), (6, 'D'), (6, 'S'), (7, 'H'), (7, 'C'), (7, 'D'), (7, 'S'), (8, 'H'), (8, 'C'), (8, 'D'), (8, 'S'), (9, 'H'), (9, 'C'), (9, 'D'), (9, 'S'), (10, 'H'), (10, 'C'), (10, 'D'), (10, 'S'), ('J', 'H'), ('J', 'C'), ('J', 'D'), ('J', 'S'), ('Q', 'H'), ('Q', 'C'), ('Q', 'D'), ('Q', 'S'), ('K', 'H'), ('K', 'C'), ('K', 'D'), ('K', 'S'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'S')]
```

You have to use `list()` because **[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) in Python 3 does create an immutable sequence type**, not a list.